# haskell checking String length - Non-exhaustive patterns exception

Tags: haskell

Why does length function work well when checking for Strings that are >1 and it gives **Non-exhaustive patterns in function** error for ones that are exatly length 1?

Here is my code:

```
    length' :: String -> String 
    length' (x:x2:xs) = if length(x:x2:xs) == 1
                           then "length is 1"
                           else "length is > 1" 
    length' "" = ""
```

Example:

```
input : "aa"
output: "length is > 1"

input : "a" 
output: "*** Exception: untitled.hs:(169,1)-(172,15): Non-exhaustive patterns in function length'
```

However:

```
        length' :: String -> String 
        length' (x:xs) = if length(x:xs) == 1
                               then "length is 1"
                               else "length is > 1" 
        length' "" = ""
```

Example:

```
input : "a"
output: "length is 1"
```

Comment: You have a pattern for a string of length 2+ and 0, but you do not have a pattern for length 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
length' :: String -> String 
length' (x:x2:xs) = if length(x:x2:xs) > 1
                    then "length is >1"
                    else length'(x:x2:xs)

length' (x:xs) = if length(x:xs) == 1
                    then "length is 1"
                    else ""

length' "" = ""
```

This solves the problem for me. (x:x2:xs) is a pattern for String of length 2+ and 0 as @Brady Dean said. Now when String with the length of 1 is passed to this function it will call the function again and now it will have a pattern for 1+ and 0.

Comment: The condition `length(x:x2:xs) > 1` can't possibly be false, so that `if` statement is unnecessary since the `else` can never be executed. The other `if` statement is also unnecessary because if `length (x:xs)` weren't 1 (that is if `xs` weren't empty), the first pattern would have matched already. With that in mind, we can also conclude that the pattern `x:xs` is equivalent to `[x]` in this case because, as I said, the previous pattern would already have matched if there were more than one element.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the case for the single element in the string.

There is also no need for if else. A simple pattern matching can solve the problem.

The way the cases of pattern matching are placed are important. The base case should be first. In this case it may not matter as there is no recursion. But still it's better to write in that way as it is easy to read.

```
length' :: String -> String
length' "" = ""
length' [x] = "length is 1"
length' _ = "length is > 1"
```

In the last line we don't use the argument anywhere, hence _.